# Cisco ASA5505 site-to-site VPN doesn't establish tunnel to remote peer

Tags: vpn, ipsec

The remote peer can start the tunnel successfully when accessing my local network like pinging a local host, however, the tunnel cannot be automatically started from the local side.

The log shows no signs of starting VPN tunnel when I trying to access the remote network.

Does anybody encountered this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a config mismatch between the peers. Both phase 1 and phase 2 parameters, as the SA lifetime, and also the ACLs (in a reverse way) must match.

You may check for a similar issue [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/202711).

(Note: I opened it as an answer as my punctuation won't allow me to add comments)